# PHP: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'users'

Tags: php

I get error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'users' in ... userlist.php;
It's a code of class userlist:

```
require_once("/var/www/html/Narkomania.pl/app/objects/user.php");

/* Userlist file */

class UserList
{
    private static $users = array();

    public function addUser($key)
    {
        array_push($users, $key);
    }

    public function removeUser($name)
    {
        foreach ($this->users as $user) {
            if($user->getName() == $name)
            {
                $this->users = array_diff($this->users, array($user));
            }
        }
    }

    public function getUserByName($name)
    {
        foreach ($this->users as $user) {
            if($user->getName() == $name)
            {
                return $user;
            }
        }
    }

    public function userExist($name)
    {
        foreach (self::users as User::$user) {
            if(User::$user->getName() == $name)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using this class and full error message.

Comment: Er, please, don't add more of this code. ;) But the line number from the error message would have been nice: it would have immediately pointed to the mistake (a missing `$`) @EduardoGalvan pointed out under Yes92's answer... Considering that, and several other gross mistakes in the piece, matching the apparent total lack of effort from OP (who seems to have also abandoned his q.), and the nature of the question... First time I say this, but it's beyond repair, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is how you use the variable `$users`. You can't access `$users` with `$this->users`, because it is a static variable. So you must always use `self::$users`. Also, change this method

```
public function addUser($key)
{
    array_push(self::$users, $key);
}
```

Comment: Dont' forget the `self::$users` in the foreach of the userExists function